# How to set_facts with an dictionary, where I reference a inventory item?

Tags: ansible

I try to access a dictionary value from an host_var inventory.

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict']['{{ aws_region }}']
```

will output the correct value:

```
TASK [get_aws_facts : debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-AWS-Site1] => 
  hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict']['eu-central-1']: '0'
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-AWS-Site2] => 
  hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict']['eu-central-1']: '0'
ok: [1-Africa-ECV-AWS-Site3] => 
  hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict']['sa-east-1']: '1'
ok: [1-Africa-ECV-AWS-Site4] => 
  hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict']['sa-east-1']: '1'
```

However, if I try to set_facts with the same command:

```
- set_fact:
    region_index: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict']['{{ aws_region }}'] }}"
```

I get this error:

```
TASK [get_aws_facts : set_fact] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [1-Europe-ECV-AWS-Site1]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{ aws_region }}'
  
    The error appears to be in '/home/admin/silverpeak-cisco-poc-automation/roles/get_aws_facts/tasks/main.yml': line 29, column 3, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
    - set_fact:
      ^ here
fatal: [1-Europe-ECV-AWS-Site2]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{ aws_region }}'
  
    The error appears to be in '/home/admin/silverpeak-cisco-poc-automation/roles/get_aws_facts/tasks/main.yml': line 29, column 3, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
    - set_fact:
      ^ here
fatal: [1-Africa-ECV-AWS-Site3]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{ aws_region }}'
  
    The error appears to be in '/home/admin/silverpeak-cisco-poc-automation/roles/get_aws_facts/tasks/main.yml': line 29, column 3, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
    - set_fact:
      ^ here
fatal: [1-Africa-ECV-AWS-Site4]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{ aws_region }}'
  
    The error appears to be in '/home/admin/silverpeak-cisco-poc-automation/roles/get_aws_facts/tasks/main.yml': line 29, column 3, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
    - set_fact:
      ^ here
```

The problem is: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict']['**{{ aws_region }}**'] }}"

Can somebody please show me how to correctly set_facts, where I use an inventory variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already put the quoted double braces `"{{ }}"` in front and behind the expression. Any unquoted tag inside the expression is a variable and will be expanded before evaluation. Fix the syntax

```yaml
- set_fact:
    region_index: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['aws_regions_dict'][aws_region] }}"
```

Comment: great! Thanks, that was really a "basic" error, but at least I understand it. What I miss is a deep dive explanation about all those "basic" and "advanced" usage of variables, I always try it until I get the result :)